# roster.getEntities() always return null aSmack android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I want to make a chat application using xmpp and asmack but I am facing a problem: I am unable to get all the users on the server. First I made a connection then I logged into it and then I tried to retrieve the users but I always get an empty Collection.

```
public void connect() {

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
            "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create a connection
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                        + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }
            try {
                // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                // Set the status to available
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendPacket(presence);
                setConnection(connection);

                // here in roster i always get null.

                Collection<RosterEntry> roster = connection.getRoster()
                        .getEntries();

                for (RosterEntry entry : roster) {
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "--------------------------------------");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "User: " + entry.getUser());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Name: " + entry.getName());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Type: " + entry.getType());


                }
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                        + USERNAME);
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    t.start();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Which version of aSmack are you using?

Comment: yeah, well, that's like a 4 year old version. Try aSmack 4.0.0.

Comment: now I am using asmack-android-8-4.0.0 and i gives me exception   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration

Comment: @Raghunandan link is broken .. can you update it plz

Comment: @chhameed i have no clue why the link is broken. I have deleted the comment

Answer (score 0):

For getting rosters just search for a plugin called registration properties or if it is pre installed search for it in the users section.

Then check the Enable automatically adding of new users to a group.
Also in the bottom create a new default group so that when a new user will be created it will be automatically added to this default group.

After that run the same code you will get all the users present on the xmpp protocol based server.